# Linux commands pipe: using iwlist with grep to display two piece of information

Tags: linux, grep

I use

```
sudo iwlist [My Wifi interface] scan
```

to get a list of all the information of access points around me e.g. the result below

```
Cell 39 - Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:""
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000312d7ef1a6
                Extra: Last beacon: 520ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0000
                IE: Unknown: 01088C929824B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD1917FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD07000B8601040812
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

---

Also, I can use

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID
```

to get the ESSID only e.g. the result below

```
ESSID:"wifi1"
ESSID:"wifi2"
ESSID:"wifi3"
```

---

My question is:
How can I use grep, or any other command for that matter, to get to display both "ESSID" and "Signal level"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the regular expression to just catch multiple words, like this:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep 'ESSID\|Signal level'
```

See the documentation of grep [online](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html) or using `man grep` in your terminal.

Comment: this is a right way, using a simple `OR` will match either

Comment: Thank you! That is just what I wanted

Comment: @WaleedMohammad If that answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @jadsq I didn't know it works this way. Thank you for the heads up